# Rubocop cop to find out if method is present on class

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have the following class:

```
class XXX
  def aa
  end

  def authorized?
    false
  end

  def bb
  end
end
```

And want to ensure method `authorized?` is present with Rubocop. The following code works in Rubocop console:

```
code = "
class XXX
  def aa
  end

  def authorized?
    false
  end

  def bb
  end
end
"
node = RuboCop::ProcessedSource.new(code, RUBY_VERSION.to_f).ast
NodePattern.new('(class ... (begin (def :aa ...)(def :authorized? ...)(def :bb ...) ) )').match(node)
```

Last line returns `true`. However, I don't want to be dependent on any methods. So I replaced the last line with

```
NodePattern.new('(class ... (begin (...)(def :authorized? ...)(...) ) )').match(node)
```

And it works, code doesn't depend on the name of methods. But! I also want to make it work when no other methods are present, or if there any more methods.

Basically, the final goal is to check if method is defined on class. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the Rubocop and node parsing methods, part of this, but can you just use regular Ruby introspection?

`XXX.instance_methods.include?(:authorized?)`

If it needs to be on the `XXX` class itself (as opposed to any included modules or superclasses),

`XXX.instance_methods.include?(:authorized?) && XXX.instance_method(:authorized?).owner == XXX`